# Dynamic Spring Message Source

Tags: spring, message

I'm about to extend org.springframework.context.support.AbstractMessageSource that will allow me to dynamically add and edit messages in Spring. I'm planning on storing these values in a database. Is there something out there that does this already? Is there a different approach I should think of?

Here are the requirements:

- I have to be able to add messages
- I have to be able to edit messages
- These adds and edits should take place immediately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure.

Develop custom MessageSource and set it as parent to existing (for example based on property files).

```
    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basenames">
        <list>
            <value>message/messages</value>
        </list>
    </property>

    <property name="parentMessageSource">
        <bean class=com.example.DatabaseMessageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this, but it sound reasonable. Thanks for the response!